# How to share WebAssembly code between projects in multiple languages?

Tags: sdk, webassembly

I'm developing SDKs in a variety of languages (NodeJS, Java, Python, Go, etc) for a project of mine. There is some core algorithmic logic in these SDKs that absolutely must behave the same in all SDKs. Rather than write this logic in each language, I want to write it once in something like AsssemblyScript (compiled to WebAssembly) and then invoke a runtime in each language.

I can imagine having a Git repo containing this AssemblyScript that compiles to WebAssembly, but I'm not sure how to share this compiled WebAssembly with each SDK repository.

Is there a best practice for doing something like this?

Right now I'm just thinking about hacky solutions like having each SDK project pull the compiled WebAssembly file from Git as part of the build process.

Is there a better method?

Comment: You can shoot me an email at the address in my profile, if you want. I am really interested in this space.

Answer (score 0):

You are already on the right path. The problem you want to solve is the usual one with sharing build artifacts between different repos.

Solutions I would recommend:

- Your solution. You have a `core` WebAssembly library that you can import. The cleanest solution is to have it as a `git submodule` that gets cloned and built in all the other SDKs. No external dependencies, just what you need. The nicest advantage here is that you can use any WebAssembly language to write your `core` part.
- Another variation of this is distributing the core part through some package managers. Package managers started adding support for WebAssembly natively. `nodejs` is easy to support this way. You build your `core` library and place it on the `npm` registry, and in the SDK you just add it as a dependency. See [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esbuild-wasm?activeTab=code) for an example of a package that has `.wasm` files.  Python's `pypi` also has support for wasm-based packages now. You can check [here](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic-core/blob/d6e7890b36ef21cb28180a7f5b1479da2319012d/.github/workflows/ci.yml#L225-L269) for an example.
- [Another](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=36037531) [way](https://github.com/y-crdt/y-crdt) is to build the core in Rust, offer ffi bindings to other possible targets--so no WebAssembly to bridge Rust <-> C, for example--and use WebAssembly to also target the browser. This way *may* lead to faster SDKs, as you don't need to execute the intermediary WebAssembly, but feels clunkier than the other two.

I think this [project](https://github.com/multiversx) may also solve the problem that you are trying to solve (you can see the SDKs there and WebAssembly being used).

You can also look at how [this](https://github.com/jetli/create-yew-app) project packages `npm` and `cargo` dependencies together--notice the `package.json` and `Cargo.toml` files in the same directory--this works more from rust to other languages though.

Solutions that I would not recommend:

- Unifying all the SDKs into a monorepo. This solves the artifact problem, as everything is now in the same place, but every `git clone` has to bring in a lot of code that you are potentially not interested in, just so you can get the SDK you want.
- Using `git lfs` to commit the artifact straight into the source.

Comment: I decided on distributing my WASM via npm. I can pull it in via npm or via a GET request to unpkg.com

This works well for me since some of my usages of this WASM is in public SDKs so the WASM has to be publicly available already.